# TSQL 2012 Server Data Type Error Msg varchar convert float (SUM only values)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum, message

I have a simple code below to sum the total amount of financial impact.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [MONTH], 
    [YEAR],
    [FY] AS [Quarter],
    SUM(CAST([Financial Impact] AS FLOAT)) AS AmountFinancialImpact
FROM t
    GROUP BY [MONTH], [YEAR], [FY]
```

I have the following error message.

[image]

Financial Impact in table t has the following values (NULL, BLANK, and ".")

[image]

I only want to SUM if there's a value in the field. I get a monthly file to import into the DB and I'm not responsible to validate the data coming in.

Is there away I can by-pass anything that isn't a value to be summed.

Comment: Non of the 3 possible values can be converted to something useful.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Cmpmd2: can you please descrribe your DataType of column [Financial Impact]??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [MONTH], 
       [YEAR],
       [FY] AS [Quarter],
       SUM( CAST( CASE WHEN [Financial Impact] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE [Financial Impact] END ) AS FLOAT) ) AS AmountFinancialImpact
  FROM t
GROUP BY [MONTH], [YEAR], [FY]
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '9355.881385' to data type int.

Comment: WHat is the data type of the column Financial Impact ?

Comment: Its nvarchar(255)

Answer (score 0):

> ***TRY_CAST*** & ***ISNULL***

```
SUM(ISNULL(TRY_CAST([Financial Impact] AS FLOAT),0))
```

Best way to write a query when you never know the exact value of each field and you want to perform some mathematical operation.

> **Try this:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [MONTH], 
    [YEAR],
    [FY] AS [Quarter],
    SUM(ISNULL(TRY_CAST([Financial Impact] AS FLOAT),0)) AS AmountFinancialImpact
FROM t
    GROUP BY [MONTH], [YEAR], [FY];
```

Just use `TRY_CAST` & `ISNULL` parallelly.